# Trying to access array offset on value of type null sql error

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I have a boolean column in my table called "verified". I'm trying to check if verified is equal to 0 "false", and if it is I want to display my error. Here is the line of code

```
// If User Click the Login Button
if(isset($_POST['logbtn'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $verified = "";

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE verified=?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('b', $verified);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $_SESSION['verified'] = $user['verified'];

    if($_SESSION['verified'] == 0){
        $errors['verified'] = "Please verify your Email";
    }
```

Instead of checking if the column is 0, i get the error "Trying to access array offset on value of type null"

Comment: A side comment: your SQL has no sense. You can't verify the specific user from the database by loading all users by a boolean flag "verified".

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to handle one of your variables as an array, when it's value is null, thus you get this error message: "Trying to access array offset on value of type null"

Comment: Well, instead of downgrading me could you elaborate and enlighten me on how to fix this issue? I've just recently took an interest to coding.

Comment: UPDATE: I've changed '  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE verified=?"; ' to '$sql = "SELECT verified FROM users";  ' and now it works, but I get the error "bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement.

Comment: You need to show us the full error message. As someone said before you SQL makes very little sense, because you select a random row. If you want to check for a particular record you need to select where id=? and verified=?. Also mysqli type should be `s` instead of `b`. You are not sending binary data.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `if (empty($_SESSION['verified']))`
So it will return true if value of `$user['verified']` is 0 / null / empty string / false

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us the full error message, but most likely the issue is that there were no records returned from database. You should be checking for a single user record instead.

```
if (isset($_POST['logbtn'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($user = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION['verified'] = $user['verified'];
    } else {
        // There is no such user in the database.
        $_SESSION['verified'] = false;
    }

    if (!$_SESSION['verified']) {
        $errors['verified'] = "Please verify your Email";
    }
}
```

I changed your SQL to get records matching only that username (assuming it is a unique user identifier) and then I check if anything was fetched from the database. I also changed mysqli type to `s` because you should not use binary type in this situation.